# Java swing not drawing paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

Im trying to draw a simple rectangle on a frame with some scrollbars and textfields(just testing) but the paintComponent its not showing, ive seen some similar cases here but i cant manage to make it work, any help please?

```
package appletdeslizadores;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class frame extends JPanel {

    JFrame f1;
    JPanel p1, p2;
    JLabel lbl1, lbl2, lbl3;
    JTextField txtfld1, txtfld2, txtfld3;
    JScrollBar sbar1, sbar2, sbar3;       


    public frame() {

        f1 = new JFrame("Applet ScrollBars");
        f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f1.setSize(380, 350);
        f1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());  
        p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3,10,10));
        lbl1 = new JLabel("Scroll Bar 1");
        lbl2 = new JLabel("Scroll Bar 2");
        lbl3 = new JLabel("Scroll Bar 3");
        sbar1 = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL, 0, 10, 0, 255);
        sbar2 = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL, 0, 10, 0, 255);
        sbar3 = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL, 0, 10, 0, 255);
        txtfld1 = new JTextField(3);
        txtfld1.setText(String.valueOf(sbar1.getValue()));
        txtfld1.setEditable(false);
        txtfld2 = new JTextField(3);
        txtfld2.setText(String.valueOf(sbar2.getValue()));
        txtfld2.setEditable(false);
        txtfld3 = new JTextField(3);
        txtfld3.setText(String.valueOf(sbar3.getValue()));
        txtfld3.setEditable(false);
        p1.add(lbl1);
        p1.add(lbl2);
        p1.add(lbl3);
        p1.add(sbar1);
        p1.add(sbar2);
        p1.add(sbar3);
        p1.add(txtfld1);
        p1.add(txtfld2);
        p1.add(txtfld3);
        f1.add(p1);
        f1.setVisible(true);

    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics2D g) {

        g.drawRect(50,50,70,100);
        g.setColor(Color.red);        

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new frame();


    }

}
```

Comment: 1) You never create an instance of `frame` that is added somewhere, therefore `paintComponent` never gets called. 2) It should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)`, put an `@Override` annotation above the method next time to avoid such mistakes. 3) Don't forget to call `super.paintComponent(g)` at the beginning of the `paintComponent` method.

Comment: hey man thanks for the help, i didnt really understand the instance of frame part, should i create another JFrame and add(frame) to it?

Comment: `frame`, oddly enough (maybe consider another name to avoid confusion), is a `JPanel`. To be able to see the `JPanel`, and what's drawn on it via `paintComponent(g)`, it has to be added to another component (it doesn't have to be a `JFrame`). As I don't really know the desired effect of the panel, I can only guess that `p1` should actually be a `frame` instance. If that doesn't help, please explain what exactly you want to draw where.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

You're not sticking to conventions. This is causing problems small mistakes. Your `frame` class is actually a `JPanel`, not a `JFrame`.

There are two main problems: You never added the panel to the frame, and the `paintComponent()` method has a Graphics object, not a `Graphics2D` object as a parameter.

The changes to your code are at the bottom of this answer.

### Solution

1. Stick to conventions. (You should also rename your class to a more appropriate name, but that is your choice.) Add the `@Override` annotation to your `paintComponent()` method since you wish to override this method from the original `JPanel`. If it crashes because of the annotation, it means you are not overriding correctly.
2. Change the `paintComponent()` parameter from `Graphics2D` to `Graphics`.
3. Add the `JPanel` to the `JFrame`.
4. Make sure you call `setPreferredSize()` on your `JPanel` and specify a size.
5. Call `pack()` on the `JFrame` right before making it visible so the layout manager can place everything accordingly.

Now I'm sure by the end of all this you are still not going to be happy with what you see because the code still needs some work, but at least this should give you a boost into the right direction. Also, you may want to call `setColor()` before drawing the rectangle. ;)

Hope this helped.

### Code

```
public class frame extends JPanel {

    JFrame f1;
    JPanel p1, p2;
    JLabel lbl1, lbl2, lbl3;
    JTextField txtfld1, txtfld2, txtfld3;
    JScrollBar sbar1, sbar2, sbar3;       


    public frame() {

        f1 = new JFrame("Applet ScrollBars");
        f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f1.setSize(380, 350);
        f1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());  
        p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3,10,10));
        lbl1 = new JLabel("Scroll Bar 1");
        lbl2 = new JLabel("Scroll Bar 2");
        lbl3 = new JLabel("Scroll Bar 3");
        sbar1 = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL, 0, 10, 0, 255);
        sbar2 = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL, 0, 10, 0, 255);
        sbar3 = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL, 0, 10, 0, 255);
        txtfld1 = new JTextField(3);
        txtfld1.setText(String.valueOf(sbar1.getValue()));
        txtfld1.setEditable(false);
        txtfld2 = new JTextField(3);
        txtfld2.setText(String.valueOf(sbar2.getValue()));
        txtfld2.setEditable(false);
        txtfld3 = new JTextField(3);
        txtfld3.setText(String.valueOf(sbar3.getValue()));
        txtfld3.setEditable(false);
        p1.add(lbl1);
        p1.add(lbl2);
        p1.add(lbl3);
        p1.add(sbar1);
        p1.add(sbar2);
        p1.add(sbar3);
        p1.add(txtfld1);
        p1.add(txtfld2);
        p1.add(txtfld3);
        f1.add(p1);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(512, 512));
        f1.add(this);
        f1.pack();
        f1.setVisible(true);


    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        g.drawRect(50,50,70,100);
        g.setColor(Color.red);        

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new frame();


    }

}
```